# Конфигурация Vue на Фронте и Spring на бэкенде

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js, spring-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделил по папкам Фронтенд и Бэкенд.

Мне нужно, чтобы при обращении к корню при поднятии сервака на localhost возвращался index, который на фронтенде.

Нагуглил как примерно это сделать, но все равно не получается сконфигурировать

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншотам вы используете spring boot. Могу предложить такие варианты:

1. С помощью gradle собирать frontend (например, с помощью https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) в zip-артефакт. Полученный артефакт добавить в зависимость в backend и распаковывать в /build/resources/main/static, для чего добавить в зависимость таски processResources таск распаковки.
2. Во фронтенд настроить WebPack (либо другой сборщик) для поднятия сервера и проксирования запросов в backend API (например, через http-proxy-middleware).

Comment: думаете, этих двух гайдов будет достаточно чтобы справиться с проблемой?